# findAll() directly after save() returns null for all OneToMany Collections

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I hope you all have a good time concerning the actual circumstances.
Since I could not find an answer to my problem I am asking this as a new question.
I am currently working on an application that could be used for administration. However, as I was experimenting a bit I found some weird behavior. Let me note that I would not do some of the things you see on production code. However, I'd like to get to the bottom of this and get to know the frameworks I am using even better. Now, let me show you some code:

**1. Relevant Part of the entity:**

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private boolean wareGroupMain;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="whg",cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<Medicine> whgmedicines = new HashSet<Medicine>();

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="whg_id")
    private WHG mainGroup;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mainGroup", cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<WHG> subGroups = new HashSet<WHG>();
```

**2. Relevant Part of the Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface WHGRepository extends JpaRepository<WHG,Long>{
    List<WHG> findAll();
```

**3. Relevant Part of the Service**

```
@Service
public class WHGService {

    @Autowired
    WHGRepository whgRepository;

    public List<WHG> findWHG() {

        List<WHG> allWHG = whgRepository.findAll();

        List<WHG> result = new ArrayList<WHG>();
        Stream<WHG> whgStream = allWHG.stream();

        whgStream.forEach((whg) -> {
            if (whg.isWareGroupMain()) {
                result.add(whg);
            }
        });
        whgStream.close();
        return result;
    }

    public void save(WHG whg) {
        whgRepository.save(whg);
    }
```

**4. Relevant Part of the Component**

```
private List<WHG> allwhg;
public void testIinit() {

    testInsert();
    allwhg=whgService.findWHG();
```

.
.
.
        //If I try to access now a whg of allwhg the described problem occurs at any point in this class

.
.
.

```
public void testInsert() {
    WHG whg = new WHG();

    whg.setName("Med1");
    whg.setIcon(Icon.MEDKIT);
    whg.setWareGroupMain(true);

    WHG wug = new WHG();

    wug.setName("Med2");
    wug.setIcon(Icon.DRINK2);
    wug.setWareGroupMain(true);

    WHG wag = new WHG();

    wag.setName("Med3");
    wag.setIcon(Icon.CUBES);
    wag.setWareGroupMain(false);

    WHG wig = new WHG();

    wig.setName("Med4");
    wig.setIcon(Icon.BOLT);
    wig.setWareGroupMain(false);

    wag.setMainGroup(wug);
    wig.setMainGroup(wag);


    whgService.save(wig);
    whgService.save(whg);
    whgService.save(wug);
    whgService.save(wag);
```

.
.
.

If there is not enough code for you please tell me what you need, I will add it gladly.
What happens in the Component is that I call save() to insert myself some test data, and then just "load" it from the db. If I later on now call whg.getSubgroups() (one of the objects I retrieve) it is null. This is more than funny since it 1) should have content, 2) I think I remember that hibernate might return an empty collection but not null...

So the question is, why is `whg.getSubgroups()` null when you call save() and then findAll()? Furthermore, if you repeat the above-shown insert method the first three entities will now be retrieved correctly (the ones we had the null problem before). However, the now newly saved and fetched entities have the null problem. This repeats till infinity (it is still correctly saved in the database tough).

I hope I could make my problem clear, if not please tell me so. I invested so many time for something that might be really trivial but I am not getting it and I could not find a place in the internet where my question was answered.

I am really looking forward to your helpful answer!

Best wishes,
foAW

Comment: You don't add anything to subGroups

Comment: Yes I do, please look at that snippet: 
wag.setMainGroup(wug);
wig.setMainGroup(wag);
It is many to one bidirectional... And even If I didn't per contract the return should never be null^^
And in the lower part of my answer you can see the conditions when It returns something (and the actual subgroups do return under said conditions, but not always so that seems not to be the problem.

Comment: Can you show in which method exactly `getSubgroups()` is being called? I have a pretty good guess what the problem is but without that part I cannot be sure.

Comment: I am very sorry, I would call it in 4.) just after the findAll(). However, under further inspection, it does not matter where in the component (sec.4) I call It. I am really thrilled for your guess^^

Comment: Can you try adding `@Transactional` annotation to your component method. This seems like it's some sort of lazy loading problem.

Comment: Tried it out, that does not fix the problem...